# Apache+Passenger not serving the root of the Sinatra application

Tags: apache-2.4, phusion-passenger, ruby, sinatra

Since the last Fusion Passenger update, all my Sinatra applications have stopped working on the following env: Apache (2.4.17), Phusion Passenger (5.0.21). Everything was working as expected before updating the passenger middleware.

The problem is, apache directory is trying to proceed to a listing of the public directory when I'm requesting the url (https://myapp.ch) of my vhost.

The ODD part:
If a route defined in the Sinatra controller is requested (i.e: https://myapp.ch/infos), passenger is started and the requested page is served as expected.

Here is the Virtual Host part:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  DocumentRoot /home/user1/sinatra/app1/public
  ServerName myapp.ch

  <Directory /home/user1/sinatra/app1/public>
      AllowOverride all
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      Options -MultiViews
      Require all granted
  </Directory>
```

Config.ru

```
# encoding: UTF-8

require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

require File.expand_path '../start.rb', __FILE__

run Sinatra::Application
```

Apache Log Error when requesting the root of the Sinatra App (/):

```
[Mon Oct 26 22:10:30.728795 2015] [autoindex:error] [pid 3535:tid 140103510914816] [client 176.127.182.162:50956] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/user1/sinatra/app1/public/: No matching DirectoryIndex (none) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Apache is trying to do directory listing (which has been disabled by configuration).

Has someone experience the same issue ? How to make apache launch passager and serves the root of the Sinatra app ?

Answer (score 7):

[Apparently](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phusion-passenger/jiOpv9Isua4) there is a [bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58498) in Apache 2.4.17.

Disabling the module auto index (which is the cause of the wrong behaviour, will prevent the error.

```
#LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
```

Phusion will address the issue in the realase of Passenger 5.0.22 before Apache 2.5.0 will be released.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Has commenting out the Loadmodule line the same effect as disabling the whole module? e.g `a2dismod autoindex`?

Comment: According to a2dismon doc, a2dismod enables/disables modules by sim-linking the the modules http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man8/a2enmod.8.html Should have the same effect